# @MappedSuperclass super class properties are empty after doing a select

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc

I have the following scenario:

I have a super class which has a String property "A" and a subclass @Entity which extends from the mapped super class and has another string property B.

I don't need to do inserts, I only need to do selects over table B.

But, when I query the B class, hibernate loads all properties from B, but, the mapped super class properties are not loaded, so, if I do B.getPropertyB() is contains the right values, however, if I do B.getPropertyA() it always return null.

The classes looks like this:

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseContributorEntity extends BaseEntity<Long> implements Comparable<BaseContributorEntity> {
    private String propertyA;

    @Column(name = "column_a", length = 450)
    public String getPropertyA() {
        return propertyA;
    }

    public void setPropertyA(String value) {
        this.propertyA = value;
    } 
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "work_contributor")
public class WorkContributorEntity extends BaseContributorEntity {
    .... Other properties, including @id ....

    private String propertyB;

    @Column(name = "column_b", length = 450)
    public String getPropertyB() {
        return propertyB;
    }

    public void setPropertyB(String value) {
        this.propertyB = value;
    }

    .... Other setters and getters ....

}
```

Do someone know why is this happening?

Should I overload the getters of the mapped super class A?

I'm working with hibernate 3.6.3 and JPA 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I 've used @MappedSuperclass for many years, it works well. your code example is right. Please double-check your real code, it should be some hand-error there.

Comment: I do agree with that. But shouldn't this be a comment?

Comment: I updated the class names and annotations, do you see any possible error there?

Comment: I viewed your code. It seems correct.  
Do you add @MappedSuperclass on BaseEntity class? if you want to map its properties too, you should do it.  
Can you have an unit test to create a instance of WorkContributorEntity with ***propertyA*** populated, if it works. It means the O/R mapping on it is correct.